# VBA browse file and make operations

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am trying to write a VBA macro, which browses excel files and then makes operation in the files. The code I wrote is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelctFile()
Dim intChoice As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim i As Integer

'allow the user to select multiple files
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = True
'make the file dialog visible to the user
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
'determine what choice the user made
If intChoice <> 0 Then
    'get the file path selected by the user
    For i = 1 To Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen _
        ).SelectedItems.Count
        strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen _
        ).SelectedItems(i)
        'print the file path to sheet 1
        Cells(i + 1, 2) = strPath
    Next i
End If    
End Sub


Sub ISIN()

Dim MSReport As Variant

MSReport = Range("B2").Value

Set MSReport = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="MSReport")
Range("W3:W2500").Formula = "=IF(G3="""","""",BDP(G3&"" Equity"",""ID_ISIN""))"

End Sub
```

The first Sub SelectFile chooses the files and I have the file path in cell B2. So I want to use the path from cell B2 in Sub ISIN.

If I write the address it works, but I want that the macro takes automatically the address.

Also is it possible that the changes are mada without opening the another worksheet.

Comment: what do you mean with  _"but I want that the macro takes automatically the address."_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply use an argument in `ISIN`, try this! ;)

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelctFile()
    Dim intChoice As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim i As Integer

    'allow the user to select multiple files
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = True
    'make the file dialog visible to the user
    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
    'determine what choice the user made
    If intChoice <> 0 Then
        'get the file path selected by the user
        For i = 1 To Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems.Count
            strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(i)
            ISIN strPath
            ''Add other procedures there!
            'NewProcedure strPath
        Next i
    End If
End Sub


Sub ISIN(ByVal FilePath As String)
    Dim MSReport As Excel.Workbook
    Set MSReport = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilePath)

    MSReport.Sheets("SheetName").Range("W3:W2500").Formula = _
            "=IF(G3="""","""",BDP(G3&"" Equity"",""ID_ISIN""))"

    MSReport.Save
    MSReport.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is with the first macro I select also other file for other macros

Comment: @AntonPetrov : Can be a bit more clear about this? You use the same "Open Dialog" for multiple procedures on different sub-selections? If it is for the same selection, you just have to add them where I marked it! ;)

Comment: I use the Open Dialog to also open completly excel files that I use in another macros.

Comment: @AntonPetrov : You just have to other lines after `ISIN strPath`, like `NewProcedure strPath` that I commented! So does it fix your initial problem?